# adding action to toolbar in formpage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to add a button to the toolbar in my page that derives from FormPage.
I use the code:

`Action action = some action...`

`action.setImageDescriptor(som descriptor...);`

`toolBarManager.add(action);`

When i run the editor I don't see nothing in the place were the button should be. If I'm hovering it with the mouse it changes to a hand icon. But if i click the action doesn't run.

Comment: I havent used ActionSets for quite some time, since the CommandFramework was introduced with 3.4 and it will be the successor over ActionSets. It is more declarative and powerfull. 
Do you have to do it in the way you describe it, or would it be possible for you to change to another approach? Then I can put together an answer related to the CommandFramework.

Comment: Here is a nice blog about it http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/01/commands-part-1-actions-vs-commands.html

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's your `ImageDescriptor` returning a null image.  Make sure you're creating an image that eclipse can deal with.  Is your image a `.png`, `.gif`?  Are you developing on Windows? After packaging, Java won't find it in the archive if you're case is wrong even though Windows is not case sensitive.